# Multiple calls to the Php function

Tags: php, function

my php script fails. What could be the problem?

NOTE: I need to call the function multiple times on the same page.

ERROR:
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare countLetters() (previously declared in D:\vhosts\xyz.php:6) in D:\vhosts\xyz.php on line 6

```
function testfunction($str) {
 $pattern = '/[a-z0-9\.]+/i';
 function countLetters($matches) {
   return $matches[0] . '(' . strlen($matches[0]) . ')';
 }
 return preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'countLetters', $str);
}
echo testfunction("Hello world")."<br>";
echo testfunction("Life is good")."<br>";
echo testfunction("I love you")."<br>";
```

Comment: Don't declare functions inside of other functions. Every time you call the `testfunction`, it will recreate `countLetters`

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: Move countLetters outside of testFunction

Comment: can you edit it with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't declare named functions inside of other named functions. Doing so means you'll redeclare the inner function every time you call the outer function. Move the inner function out.

```
function testfunction($str) {
 $pattern = '/[a-z0-9\.]+/i';

 return preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'countLetters', $str);
}

 function countLetters($matches) {
   return $matches[0] . '(' . strlen($matches[0]) . ')';
 }
echo testfunction("Hello world")."<br>";
echo testfunction("Life is good")."<br>";
echo testfunction("I love you")."<br>";
```